# Error 502 during Ajax post call in Flask web app

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, flask

I need to send data from my JS to my python backend to execute a pretty long function, after 1min the browser throws a 502 error whereas my function is still executing in backend. How can I force my browser to wait until my function finishes? Thank you

## app.py

```
@app.route('/rap_get_datatable', methods=["POST","GET"])
def rap_get_datatable(): 
    if request.method == 'POST':
        long_task()
```

## my HTML/JS

```
    $.ajax({
        url: '/rap_get_datatable',
        type: 'POST',
        data: array_ex,
        success: function(response){
            console.log("AJAX SUCCESS")
            ** Creation of a datatable with the data I receive after the execution of long_task()

        },
        error: function(){
            console.log("error Ajax POST")
            $('#overlay').fadeOut();
            alert("error")

        }

    }).done(function(result){

    })
```